# Hiding resource text files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, embedded-resource

I wouldlike to hide some text files from my user that my python program uses. How can I do that ? 
The ideal case would be if I had an executable made from my resources and the python code.

Comment: By "hide" do you mean "make it more convenient for the user by reducing the number of files" or do you mean "prevent the user from reading?" The former is fairly straight-forward if your project isn't too complicated (see cx_Freeze, and make your data a variable defined in a Python module). The latter is impossible. Even "make it somewhat difficult for a knowledgeable user to read" basically requires a full-time DRM team (either your own, or via commercial products).

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I meant the latter :/
Is it possible to prevent them from modifying it at least ?

Comment: No; if you ship someone data, they can modify it. If you ship them code that checks that it hasn't been modified, they can modify the code to not check. That's the nature of sending people code they can run on hardware they control. If this were possible, then copy protection would be effective and jailbreaking iPhones would be impossible. iPhone is a good thought experiment on this. Apple controls absolutely every part of the platform, from the processor to the operating system, and they can't stop jailbreaking. What can we do in a high-level language in userspace that's going to be stronger?

Comment: If you want to obfuscate, go ahead and xor the data against some key you store in the code (and maybe scramble a little bit in any way that amuses you). It won't work, but at least it won't take much time and probably won't introduce many bugs (which strong mechanisms often do). And it'll work against someone who has no idea what they're doing, so it's not totally useless.

Comment: If it's core to your business plan to protect this data, expect to spend a lot of money on an ongoing basis to constantly improve your obfuscation. At a minimum, you'll need a commercial product (and those aren't always effective; at a minimum you should expect it to be updated regularly, which you'll pay for, as people break it; if it's cheap, it's probably useless). If it's really important to you, you'll need to hire staff with background in DRM.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your explanations sir !